# When a field has value the other field must be null

Tags: hibernate

I have an entity named `Entity1` this entity has two many-to-one relation with other two entities `Entity2` and `Entity3`.

The `Entity1` must only have a relation with `Entity2` or `Entity3` each time we add a record to the `Entity1` table.

This is the hbm file of the `Entity1` :

```
<class name="Entity1" table="t_entity1_e1" optimistic-lock="version">
        <id name="id" column="e1_id">
            <generator class="native"/>
        </id>

        <property name="libelle" column="e1_libelle"/>

        <many-to-one name="entity2" column="e1_entity2" class="Entity2"/>
        <many-to-one name="entity3" column="e1_entity3" class="Entity3"/>

        <many-to-one name="someOtherEntity" column="e1_other_entity" class="SomeOtherEntity"/>
    </class>
```

So what I mean is when the column `e1_entity2` has a value the other column `e1_entity1` must be null and vice-versa.

How can I do this ? in the sql side and in the java side.

PS : I'm not using JPA.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with [class level constraints](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.0/reference/en-US/html/validator-customconstraints.html#section-class-level-constraints) in Hibernate.

Constraint definition:

```
@Target({ TYPE, ANNOTATION_TYPE })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = { Entity1ConstraintValidator.class })
@Documented
public @interface Entity1Constraint {

    String message() default "Error message";

    Class<?>[] groups() default { };

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default { };
}
```

Validator definition:

```
public class Entity1ConstraintValidator
        implements ConstraintValidator<Entity1Constraint, Entity1> {

    @Override
    public void initialize(Entity1Constraint constraintAnnotation) {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(Entity1 entity1, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        if (entity1 == null) {
            return true;
        }
        if ((entity1.getEntity2() != null) && (entity1.getEntity3()) != null)) {
            return false;   
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```